# Unable to add User Control to an existing WCF Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I developed a WCF Service, that is working nice. However, this Service does not provide any user control, and I'm trying to add this ability now.

You can find the WCF class:

```
Public Class WCF_ServicioWeb
    Implements IWCF_ServicioWeb

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function HelloWorld() As String Implements IWCF_ServicioWeb.HelloWorld
        Return My.Resources.CONST_HELLO_WORLD
    End Function

    Public Function EnviarFichero(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As Integer Implements IWCF_ServicioWeb.EnviarFichero
            'Do some ooperations.
            Return 0
    End Function

End Class
```

The OperationContracts:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IWCF_ServicioWeb

    <OperationContract()>
    Function HelloWorld() As String

    <OperationContract()>
    Function EnviarFichero(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As Integer

End Interface


<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property nombreFichero() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property lugarAdq() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property sCadenaDeTexto() As String

End Class
```

Now you can fiend the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="WCF_ServicioWeb.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Looking at the web, I have found that for introduce the user control, the class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports System.IdentityModel.Selectors
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Class CustomUserNameValidator
    Inherits UserNamePasswordValidator
    Public Overrides Sub Validate(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String)
        If ((userName = "user") And (password = "password")) Then
            'passed
        Else
            Throw New FaultException("Invalid credentials")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, **I get an error because the class *UserNamePasswordValidator*, the lib *Imports System.IdentityModel.Selectors* and the lib *Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens* are not found**. I'm working with vb.net (VS2010), and NET Framework 4.0.
Any one knows why this could be happening?
I have checked that the Tokes can be imported from the lib *System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens* instead of *System.IdentityModel.Tokens*, but I have not found how to import the *Selectors*.

And, once this clase could be added rightly to the project, how must I proceed to follow introducing the user control on the WCF?. Which modifications should I perform on the web.config file for this?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined proper Contract to all classes and methods,

```
<OperationContract()>
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/introduction-to-wcf-vb/)

This is the best approach for WCF in VB.NET, hope so this will help you,

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/introduction-to-wcf-vb/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But keep in mind that the original WCF service (without user authoring) is working fine, so the operation contracts are well defined. What I'm trying to do is to add the ability of checking user and password.

Comment: I have added the contrats to the initial question. Remember, the code poosted is working fine.